# Inheriting istream operator>>

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, operator-keyword, istream

I have a function in class `PhoneNumber`:

```
class PhoneNumber
{
protected:
    int area;
    long number;
public:
    istream& operator>>(istream& is, PhoneNumber &p){
        cout << "Enter area code : ";
        is >> p.area;
        cout << "Enter number telephone number : ";
        is >> p.number;
        return is;
    }
};
```

and another function in class like this :

```
class IntPhoneNumber::public PhoneNumber
{
    int reg;
    public 
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, IntPhoneNumber &p);
};
```

I want class `IntPhoneNumber` to inherit and use `operator>>` in class `PhoneNumber`.

Comment: Please tag the language and fix indentation of your code.

Comment: Create a virtual `get(std::istream&)` method in the derived class. Create a non-member operator overload inserter for the base class and call `p.get(is)`. In the derived class you can override the function so you have different insertion semantics.

Answer (score 2):

A nicely scalable way of doing this is to delegate from `operator>>` to a virtual member function of `PhoneNumber`, and then provide overloads in derived classes - which can call back into the parent class if they wish.

```
class PhoneNumber {
protected:
    int area;
    long number;
public:
  friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, PhoneNumber &p);

  virtual void getFromStream(istream& is) {
        cout << "Enter area code : ";
        is >> area;
        cout << "Enter number telephone number : ";
        is >> number;
  }
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, PhoneNumber &p) {
   p.getFromStream(is);
}
```

Now you can overload like this:

```
class IntPhoneNumber::public PhoneNumber {
    int reg;
    virtual void getFromStream(istream& is) {
      PhoneNumber.getFromStream(is);
      cout << "Enter reg :";
      is >> reg;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First you have to declare your extractor as friend:

```
class PhoneNumber
{
protected:
    int area;
    long number;
public: 
    ...
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, PhoneNumber &p);
};
```

You then defined `operator>>` outside of the class:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, PhoneNumber &p) 
{
        cout << "Enter area code : ";
        is >> p.area;
        cout << "Enter number telephone number : ";
        is >> p.number;
        return is;

};
```

Now with this construct already, you could use the same `operator>>` for the derived `IntPhoneNumber`, if you wouldn't care for the region code:

```
struct IntPhoneNumber:public PhoneNumber
{
protected:
    int reg;
public:
    ...
};
```

This code will compile and handle `IntPhoneNumber` exactly as `PhoneNumber`:

```
PhoneNumber n;
cout<< "Request phone number"<<endl; 
cin >> n;  
cout<< "Request phone int number"<<endl; 
IntPhoneNumber ni; 
cin>>ni;
```

Now if you would like to override operator>> for `IntPhoneNumber`, but reuse what you've already written for `PhoneNumber`, it's not a problem either.  Just define another friend and use casting:

```
class IntPhoneNumber:public PhoneNumber
{
protected:
    int reg;
public:
    ...
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, IntPhoneNumber &p);
};

istream& operator>>(istream& is, IntPhoneNumber &p) 
{
    cout << "Enter area code : ";  // do the specific
    is >> p.reg;
    return is >> static_cast<PhoneNumber&>(p);  // and call the general one
};
```

Here a [live demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/CNSlfT) applying this for input and output.

***Remark:*** It's ok for a proof of concept.  But normally for an extractor overload (i.e. `operator>>`) you shouldn't display on `cout`:  if the same extractor would be used for reading data from a file, the screen would be submerged by messages for the user and the reading operation would be slowed down.  This is why I've added some `if (is==cin)` in the live demo.